# How to transfer data from tables to web forms?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a table that displays information through a list of dictionaries.

This is the program :

```
  <div class = "col-md-8" >
          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">


            <thead> <!-- En-tête du tableau -->
              <tr>
                <th> Host Name </th>
                <th> Hardware </th>
                <th> Fixed-Address </th>
                <th> Comment </th>
              <tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody> <!-- Corps du tableau -->
              {% for item in items %}
                <tr id="confirm">
                {% for key in  [ 'host','hardware','fixed_address','comment' ] %}
                  <td> {{ item[key].decode('utf-8') }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
```

What I would like to do is to be able to modify it or add a new entry, that's not what I am going to ask here because before that I need to do the following:

Basically, I need to make every row act as a link, when I click on it (the row) I should be redirected to a web page with web forms and those web forms will be filled with the data from the table cells.

How can I do it? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```
<thead> <!-- En-tête du tableau -->
          <tr>
            <th> Host Name </th>
            <th> Hardware </th>
            <th> Fixed-Address </th>
            <th> Comment </th>
            <th> View </th>
          <tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody> <!-- Corps du tableau -->
          {% for item in items %}
            <tr id="confirm">
            {% for key in  [ 'host','hardware','fixed_address','comment' ] %}
              <td> {{ item[key].decode('utf-8') }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
          <a href="{{ url_for(<Function to navigate to>) }}">View</a>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
           </tbody>
     </table>
  </div>
```

That function inside url_for should be the function which displays data and should renders page for displaying data.

Comment: Your link will just send me to another page without doing anything, on top of it it'll display "View" many times.